# Prisma Migrate could not create the shadow database

Tags: database, prisma

So whenever i try to use my database from elephantsql.com, i get this following error:

`Prisma Migrate could not create the shadow database. Please make sure the database user has permission to create databases. Read more about the shadow database (and workarounds) at https://pris.ly/d/migrate-shadow`

I have tried to reset the password but still getting the same error.